# Automating file copy

Tags: shell-script

I want to copy all files from my Documents of the last 24 hours in a file. And after that I want to select every line in the file, which should be the path of the document, and copy it to an other directory. But I have a problem.

This is to copy the path and name of the documents in a file :

```
find ./Documents -mtime -1 -type f > ./Documents/renc.txt
```

This works.

I get all the Documents created or modified in this file with their path for the last 24 hours.

But then, when I want to give a value 'b' to be able to copy the file after that I can't.

```
b= `sed -n "3p" ~/Documents/renc.txt`

bash: ~/Documents/test.odt: No such file or directory
```

If it is not clear, what I want is to get ~/Documents/test.odt from the file renc.txt which should get the value 'b'. Then have an other command line

```
cp $b ~/Others
```

After of course, they will be few documents so I will add a loop to get every lines of the file.

Thank you for your help,

Mat

Comment: Remove whitespace after the `=` sign.

Comment: Some questions. 1. Have you considered a situation where the script doesn't run for 24 hours - what happens to the files created after the last copy but more then 24 hours ago? 2. Is this a backup directory, and if so have you considered using `rsync` to keep it up to date? 3. Can we create the list a files as a side effect of the copy?

Comment: Can Explain he question step by step so that it will be helpful

Comment: Yeah actually I just thought of getting the PATH/documents from a file who store the new documents. But it works perfectly with rsync (I didn't know this one). I want to use it with ssh to transfer to an other computer every 24 hours to have a backup. Here's my solution                                              rsync --backup $(find ./Documents -mtime -1 -type f) ~/Documents/Backup                                                                                                     Thank you for your help

Comment: Isn't the point of `rsync` that you would *not* need `find` anymore?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really know rsync at the moment so I used something I knew and it seems to work just fine. I am going to check if they are any other way with rsync anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're really asking is, "How can I copy my documents to a different directory every day, for a backup?" then you can use `rsync`. This tool will consider every file in the source tree, but will only copy those files are newer in the source tree:

```
rsync -av Documents/ /path/to/backupDocuments/
```

If you're asking, "How can I copy my documents to a remote server every day, for a backup?" then you can use `rsync` running over `ssh`. This version will copy only the necessary *parts* of files that are newer in the source tree:

```
rsync -av Documents/ remoteuser@remotehost:backupDocuments/
```

If you really just want to find documents created or modified in the last 24 hours and copy them somewhere (bearing in mind that files older than this may get skipped if you don't run your script precisely every 24 hours), then this may help. It'll create a list of files in `/tmp/copied_files.list` on the way :

```
find Documents -depth -mtime -1 fprint /tmp/copied_files.list -print0 |
    pax -0 -d -rw /path/to/backupDocuments/
```

All things considered, I'd recommend the `rsync` as the better option.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll probably use all of them